# Looping AsyncTask Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to loop through some records in my table and for each record, use a value as a parameter to;

1. get a webpage to parse some html
2. get some JSON data to parse and get a couple of values from

These both worked perfectly by themselves, but I can not get them both working in an AsyncTask. I have the code here. I know I am probably way off, but if someone could give me a nudge into how my thinking is off, I'd really appreciate it.

On the first line

```
    private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
```

I get

```
Class FetchWebsiteData must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method doInBackground(params...) in 'AsynTask'
```

As an error message and underlined in red.

```
private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(summary.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String urls3, String result3) {

        helper = new TaskDBHelper(summary.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor dataCount = sqlDB.rawQuery("select TASK from " + TaskContract.TABLE, null);
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        dataCount.moveToFirst();
        do {
            temp.add(dataCount.getString(0));
        } while (dataCount.moveToNext());
        dataCount.close();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : temp)
        {
            wallBal = s;

            //--------------------------------------------

            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL+wallBal).get();
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(document.text());
                balance = new Double(doc.text());
                helper = new TaskDBHelper(summary.this);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB2 = helper.getWritableDatabase();


                String sql9 = String.format("UPDATE " + TaskContract.TABLE + " SET " + TaskContract.Columns.OLDBAL + " = " + TaskContract.TABLE + "." + TaskContract.Columns.BAL + " WHERE task='" + wallBal + "'");
                sqlDB2.execSQL(sql9);

                String sql = String.format("UPDATE " + TaskContract.TABLE + " SET " + TaskContract.Columns.BAL + " = " + balance + " WHERE task='" + wallBal + "'");
                sqlDB2.execSQL(sql);
                Cursor dataCount2 = sqlDB.rawQuery("select " + TaskContract.Columns.OLDBAL + " from " + TaskContract.TABLE + " WHERE " + TaskContract.Columns.TASK + " = '" + wallBal + "'", null);

                dataCount2.moveToFirst();
                oldbalance = dataCount2.getDouble(0);

                if(balance != oldbalance) {
                    make();
                }
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(result3);
                String str = "";
                JSONArray articles3 = json3.getJSONArray("data");

                str += "articles length = "+json3.getJSONArray("data").length();
                str += "\n--------\n";
                str += "names: "+articles3.getJSONObject(0).getString("MasternodeIP");
                str += "\n--------\n";


                MNIP = articles3.getJSONObject(0).getString("MasternodeIP");
                Sts = articles3.getJSONObject(0).getString("ActiveCount");

                helper = new TaskDBHelper(summary.this);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB22 = helper.getWritableDatabase();

                String sql91 = String.format("UPDATE " + TaskContract.TABLE + " SET " + TaskContract.Columns.IP + " = '" + MNIP + "' WHERE task='" + task + "'");
                sqlDB22.execSQL(sql91);

                String sql10 = String.format("UPDATE " + TaskContract.TABLE + " SET " + TaskContract.Columns.STATUS + " = '" + Sts + "' WHERE task='" + task + "'");
                sqlDB22.execSQL(sql10);


                updateUI();


            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------
        }


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------







        //return null;
        return GET(urls3);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        updateUI();

    }
}
```

Comment: You are also going to want to override doInBackground and onPostExecute

Comment: You should change AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> to AsyncTask<Void, String, String>.

Also, you are missing @Override above the doInBackground method.

Comment: @user3572565 Did you resolve `Class FetchWebsiteData must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method doInBackground(params...) in 'AsynTask'`?

Answer (score 5):

Change this

```
protected String doInBackground(String urls3, String result3)
```

To

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args)
```

Then declare your variables like so inside your doInBackground function

```
String urls3 = args[0];
String result3 = args[1];
```

You will also need to correct your onPostExecute to

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
```

And your class declaration to

```
private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

Comment: @ajb You are right, he needs to the argument in his onPostExecute as well. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it again, I don't think the `String...` parameter type will work either since `Params` is `Void`.  Something else needs to be fixed.

Comment: @abj That is correct as well, the class declaration needs to be changed to the appropriate types. Then, I think, it should be good.

Comment: I also had to change to AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Answer (score 0):

The `doInBackground` method is defined like this:

```
protected abstract Result doInBackground (Params... params)
```

To override it, you need to give it the same parameter list, i.e. a parameter with type `Params...`.   Here, `Params`, the first type parameter of `AsyncTask`, is `Void`.

Furthermore, the result type has to be `Result`, which in this case is `Void`, since `Result` is the third type parameter of `AsyncTask`, and you're using `Void` as the third parameter.

So the only way to write a method that overrides `doInBackground` would be

```
Void doInBackground(Void... params)
```

which I don't think is what you want, since you seem to want the parameters to be strings.  So I believe you'll need to change the first type parameter of `AsyncTask`, which should probably be

```
private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
```

If you really want `doInBackground` to return a `String`, you'll also need to change the third (`Result`) type parameter:

```
private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
```

Also, the parameter list has to have the same types; you can't override the method with

```
protected String doInBackground(String urls3, String result3)
```

but instead you need

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

This appears to be acceptable also:

```
protected String doInBackground(String[] params)
```

If necessary, verify at run time that you got exactly two parameters by checking `params.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending AsyncTask < Void, String, Void > which means you are passing String.. as an argument to doInBackground method and the doInBackground method will return Void.

But, in your code doInBackground method is returning String. So, you should change AsyncTask < Void, String, Void > to AsyncTask < Void, String, String >.

Also, you are missing @Override above the doInBackground method.

Hope it helps! :)